# Position divs like in a grid/table without losing automatic floating

Tags: javascript, css

For instance, I have 10 left-float divs which take 20% of the container width with an aspect ratio of 1:1 (made using jQuery):

```
width: 20%;
float: left;
```

http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc494/Golitan11/example1_zps7a24eb88.png

Now, when I click one of them, they take 40% of the container width (without losing the aspect ratio of 1:1) and the image is changed to a Soundcloud iFrame. In this example, I clicked the second one:

http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc494/Golitan11/example2_zps9b7a9f48.png

The problem is, as you can see, the floating. In fact, I would like to fill the hole on the left. I tried using a table instead of divs, but in this situation, it makes it too hard to move the s to other  (even with jQuery) when the clicked  is getting colspan/rowspan. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Actually, my website is a school project where I can't use external libraries/modules except jQuery (because I am learning it). Is it possible to do it all by myself?

Comment: The nature of floats would make it really tricky to fill in that gap to the left. The masonry approach would involve a lot of math though.

Comment: Is the number of elements fixed to 10, or is it dynamic? And is this supposed to act responsive in any way?

Comment: It is dynamic, but only size-responsive (the number of "column" is never changing). In other words, I want 5 divs at all time on each row and the number of row is undefined. When one of those divs are clicked, the div is now taking the space of 4 divs (2x2).